# Mocking Functions with Complex Module Structures

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a function `funcA` that lives in `folderA.folderB.foo.py`

```py
def funcA():
     ...
     return 0 if (some condition) else 1
```

That is then used in `classB.funcB` in `folderA.folderC.bar.py`.

```py
from folderA.folderB.foo import funcA

class B:
    def funcB(self):
        return_code = funcA()
        return 'A' if return_code == 0 else 'B'
```

Now in my testing suite I want to test `classB.funcB` for both possible `return_codes` that can be returned from `funcA`, but I am not sure how to mock the return value of `funcA` in a test for `funcB`

I have tried using `@patch(folderA.folderB.foo.funcA)` as well as `@patch(folderA.folderC.bar.funcA)`, but neither of these have worked. Based on what I have read from the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) it seems that the latter is meant to work, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your not working test, otherwise it is difficult to see what goes wrong. At a first glance, your second attempt at patching should work.